# C#: Dictionary or list of pairs

Tags: c#, performance

I'm reading a large amount of data that I need to store as pairs of corresponding values. Then I'll need to look up the corresponding values for the keys, once for almost each key.

Since I'll be searching for each key only once, is it worth it to use a Dictionary, or would it be better in terms of performance to use List<Pair<...>> here?

Comment: Why would you use lists instead? If you plan to remove them after they are done, from what I understand, removing is much worse for performance than the performance you will be saving, since the list may have to move elements around, but I am not sure.

Comment: *"Wouldn't it be better in terms of performance"* - [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) to find out.

Comment: Better performance in what way? You really only mention adding and looking up. Obviously looking up in a Dictionary is going to be much faster, and adding to each should be roughly the same. Why/where would you expect the List to be more performant? And perhaps the most important question: Is it even going to matter at all?

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b  "Why would you use lists instead?" - I'm pretty sure that creation of a big dictionary would be more expensive than creation of a list because Dictionary should be optimized for fast keys look-up, it should hold a binary-tree or something. Regarding the removal - it's not a problem, I need it to work fast during the process, I don't care is it would be slowly deinitialized

Comment: @David thanks for the link but I'm not that much interested on finding out the truth to make measurements. I thought there may be some well-known considerations for my situation. something like "if you won't add or delete elements - use Array, use list otherwise"

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I'm pretty sure that creation of a big dictionary would be more expensive than creation of a list because Dictionary should be optimized for fast keys look-up, it should hold a binary-tree or something.

regarding "does it matter" - not critically, but I'd like to do it better way if there is such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how much data you have and how complicated it is to calculate the dictionary hashes.

Your average lookup time for the List will be N/2. For the Dictionary it will always be the same hash resolution, but these hash resolutions can be fairly expensive. Therefore, for any data set there exists some number N where the List's average lookup cost starts to exceed the hash resolution. Below this number, the List is faster. Above the number, the Dictionary is faster.

Where this breaking point happens depends on your data. I recall many years ago we used to use just 10 items as a rule of thumb, but I have no idea how valid that really is. Really, though, the **best** way to find out is to actually try both on a sample of your real data.

We also need to throw in sorting as a further wrinkle. If you know you'll need to find every item in a list exactly once, then the total cost for the basic unsorted data is N items * N/2 average lookup time. This is a O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm, which is not great. But very often you can sort the data so you know the look-ups will happen sequentially, and then walk the List. This can be **MUCH** more efficient — O(n*log(n)) — and is more likely to beat the dictionary.

Comment: if I understood correctly you propose to use sorted list + search algorithms. but isn't it basically same as dictionary?  regarding the hash calculation - the keys are short strings, so I guess it would be pretty fast

Comment: @AliqQim Don't guess. Test.